# How to conditionally set the width property of a Semantic UI React Grid column?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I would like to conditionally set the width of the columns below depending on another value but when I try to change the number constants to a variable, I get Typescript errors that they can only be set to discrete values.  Is there a good way to conditionally set this property, or do I have to write a grid column for every case?

```
          <Grid>
            <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Column width={4}>
                <Image src={"http://localhost:5000/img/" + image} />
              </Grid.Column>
              <Grid.Column width={12}>
                <Card />
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
          </Grid>
```

Comment: I added the Typescript tag to this. My guess is that this might have to do with your typings so it would be good to also indicate what version of SUIR you are using, as well as what version of the type files you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to change the values inside the `width` prop, you could use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside it. Like this:

```
<Grid.Column width={ condition ? <column number if true> : <column number if false> } />
```

Not sure if this is the best way, but this approach has helped me in structuring stuff in SUI-R.